# Unable to access external drives over the network

Tags: macos, remote-access, macos-catalina, file-sharing, screensharing

From my new powerbook pro I can connect to my iMac over the local network and access files on the iMac's internal disk. I can share the screen on the iMac and view all of the connected external storage devices. From the iMac's system preferences, I have explicitly made these eternal devices available for sharing. However, although these external devices appear in the finder on my laptop, when I attempt to access these external drives directly from the finder on my laptop I get the following error: **"The operation can't be completed because the original item for "*mydrivename*" can't be found".**

I have tried relaunching the finder on the laptop with no effect.

Can anyone help please.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question? You could ask on https://apple.stackexchage.com instead.

Comment: Re-posted to apple.stachexchange.com

Comment: they are appearing in the finder, but where?

Comment: 0


I reposted this question to apple.stackexhange.com with the solution. Basically, all that was required was to switch filesharing off and back on again on the computer directly connected to the external drives, and relaunch finder on the remote laptop.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387442/unable-to-access-external-drives-over-the-network-original-item-cant-be-found/387577#387577

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reposted this question to apple.stackexhange.com with the solution. Basically, all that was required was to switch filesharing off and back on again on the computer directly connected to the external drives, and relaunch finder on the remote laptop.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387442/unable-to-access-external-drives-over-the-network-original-item-cant-be-found/387577#387577

Answer (score 0):

The answer worked for me on a networked Mac Studio with an external drive. In Ventura 13.2.1 - Switched "File Sharing" off in "General" then on. Now all Macs on network are able to access the external drive on the Mac Studio.

Comment: Please use comment section to give feedback about another answers

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34367998)